# How to update innertext of specific node XML using powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell

I have XML file like this.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StudentList>
    <Class>
        <StudentID code="200" description="EDF">
            <SID8594>
                <RegID>8594</RegID>
                <Year>2019</Year>
                <MAJOR>
                    <Level>2.13</Level>
                </MAJOR>
                <SUBMAJOR>
                    <Level>2.13</Level>
                </SUBMAJOR>
            </SID8594>
            <SID8593>
                <RegID>8593</RegID>
                <Year>2019</Year>
                <MAJOR>
                    <Level>2.13</Level>
                </MAJOR>
                <SUBMAJOR>
                    <Level>2.13</Level>
                </SUBMAJOR>
            </SID8593>
            <SID8595>
                <RegID>8595</RegID>
                <Year>2020</Year>
                <MAJOR>
                    <Level>2.20</Level>
                </MAJOR>
                <SUBMAJOR>
                    <Level>2.20</Level>
                </SUBMAJOR>
            </SID8595>
        <StudentID code="100" description="ABC">
            <SID85AA>
                <RegID>85AA</RegID>
                <Year>2019</Year>
                <SUBMAJOR>
                    <Level>2.13</Level>
                </SUBMAJOR>
            </SID85AA>
    </Class>    
<StudentList>
```

The first case, I want to update innertext of all "Level", but only element StudentID code="100" . Is it possible to do it?

The second case, I want to update all innertext element "Level", if the element "Year" has innertext equal to "2019" . Is that possible?

Anyone can give me idea please. Thank you

Comment: You'll need to add a child `Year` element to `Level`, not simply update the InnerText of `Level`.

Comment: There are multiple nodes that have Year 2019. Any particular logic you want to use to select a particular SID ?

Comment: I don't want to use SID, no matter the SID. The simply one is, if the  <StudentID code="200"> the innertext of all level will updated. @Jawad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Search By Year only**

You can read in the xml document via and then update the required elements.

```
[xml]$studentList = Get-Content C:\temp\xml.txt
$Nodes2019 = $studentList.StudentList.Class.StudentID.ChildNodes | ? {$_.Year -eq 2019 }

# Change the values of all the elements
$Nodes2019 | ? {$_.MAJOR } | % { $_.MAJOR.LEVEL = "NewValue" }

# Save changes to new file once done.
$studentList.Save("C:\temp\newxml.txt")
```

**Search By StudentID and year**

If you want to specify a specific student ID, you can search via this,

```
$studentID = 200
$year = 2019

[xml]$studentList = Get-Content C:\temp\xml.txt

#Get all the 2019 nodes for specific Student.
$Nodes2019 = ($studentList.StudentList.Class.StudentID | ? {$_.Code -eq $studentID}).ChildNodes | ? {$_.Year -eq $year }

#Update the data you want ***WITH IF STATEMENT**
$Nodes2019 | % { if ($_.MAJOR.LEVEL) { $_.MAJOR.LEVEL = "newValueMajor"} ; if ($_.SUBMAJOR.LEVEL) { $_.SUBMAJOR.LEVEL = "newValueSubMajor" } }

#Save the data
$studentList.Save("C:\temp\newXml.txt")
```

**resulting xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StudentList>
  <Class>
    <StudentID code="200" description="EDF">
      <SID8594>
        <RegID>8594</RegID>
        <Year>2019</Year>
        <MAJOR>
          <Level>newValueMajor</Level>
        </MAJOR>
        <SUBMAJOR>
          <Level>newValueSubMajor</Level>
        </SUBMAJOR>
      </SID8594>
      <SID8593>
        <RegID>8593</RegID>
        <Year>2019</Year>
        <MAJOR>
          <Level>newValueMajor</Level>
        </MAJOR>
        <SUBMAJOR>
          <Level>newValueSubMajor</Level>
        </SUBMAJOR>
      </SID8593>
      <SID8595>
        <RegID>8595</RegID>
        <Year>2020</Year>
        <MAJOR>
          <Level>2.20</Level>
        </MAJOR>
        <SUBMAJOR>
          <Level>2.20</Level>
        </SUBMAJOR>
      </SID8595>
    </StudentID>
    <StudentID code="100" description="ABC">
      <SID85AA>
        <RegID>85AA</RegID>
        <Year>2019</Year>
        <SUBMAJOR>
          <Level>2.13</Level>
        </SUBMAJOR>
      </SID85AA>
    </StudentID>
  </Class>
</StudentList>
```

> For comparison purpose, this is the xml I used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StudentList>
    <Class>
        <StudentID code="200" description="EDF">
            <SID8594>
                <RegID>8594</RegID>
                <Year>2019</Year>
                <MAJOR>
                    <Level>2.13</Level>
                </MAJOR>
                <SUBMAJOR>
                    <Level>2.13</Level>
                </SUBMAJOR>
            </SID8594>
            <SID8593>
                <RegID>8593</RegID>
                <Year>2019</Year>
                <MAJOR>
                    <Level>2.13</Level>
                </MAJOR>
                <SUBMAJOR>
                    <Level>2.13</Level>
                </SUBMAJOR>
            </SID8593>
            <SID8595>
                <RegID>8595</RegID>
                <Year>2020</Year>
                <MAJOR>
                    <Level>2.20</Level>
                </MAJOR>
                <SUBMAJOR>
                    <Level>2.20</Level>
                </SUBMAJOR>
            </SID8595>
        </StudentID>
        <StudentID code="100" description="ABC">
            <SID85AA>
                <RegID>85AA</RegID>
                <Year>2019</Year>
                <SUBMAJOR>
                    <Level>2.13</Level>
                </SUBMAJOR>
            </SID85AA>
        </StudentID>
    </Class>    
</StudentList>
```

Comment: But I found a little problem, If the  $studentID = 200_ABC ,  This value "200_ABC" can not use. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: how do you plan to use 200_ABC to find a record? `$query = "200_ABC"; $studentID = $query.Split('_')[0]; $description = $query.Split('_')[1]` ??

Comment: No, Its not working. I just make sure again, search by StudentID is not work. I change the StudentID to "200", the level is not change.

Comment: I just ran the code with your xml and creates the xml with changes. I'll post the xml i get. XML you posted did have some errors, like missing closing tags. Copy paste the xml I posted (original) and run the code exactly as is to see how it processes it.

Comment: This is the error when I change the StudentID to 200_ABC; 200_ABC: The term '200_ABC' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,

Comment: You cant change the $studentID to anything other than a number without `;`. when you use `;`, you are running a new command and powershell is telling you that 200_ABC is not a valid cmdlet. You should enclose the value in double quotes. `$query = "200_abc;200_def"`

Comment: I change the StudentID to 200, and return this error The property 'LEVEL' cannot be found on this object.

Comment: Added an update to my response (with $studentID). Use IF statement to see if the key exists, otherwise keep going.

Comment: Yes!! You're right. In my XML file, some node does not have both MAJOR and SUBMAJOR. It works perfectly now. Thank you so much

Comment: if you dont mind, please help me to  check my other question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/60203036/11076819 . Thank you so much! @Jawad