# How to mapping a folder name using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, loops

I want to mapping an a folder to download and extract the folder.
This is the way I need to download the folder.

```
DownloadF.exe --net 10.0.0.1 --user XX --id 00 --ver A00X-F1A >> result.txt
```

I have 26 version to mapping, which are

```
A00X-F1A ... A00X-F1Z (the last character is A - Z)
```

If the `result.txt` contain of this string "folder available". It means the version is correct, then stop the looping or checking other version.

I must check the version start from `A00X-F1Z, A00X-F1Y, A00X-F1X, ... A00X-F1A`.
Anyone can give me idea please.

```
##Updated
$Version = "A00X-F1"
$List_Ver = 90..65 | ForEach-Object{"$Version" + [char]$_}
$n = 0
foreach ($list in $List_Ver){    
    while ($Result -notcontains "Folder Available")
    {
        $n++
        & DownloadF.exe --net 10.0.0.1 --user XX --id 00 --ver $list >> $list.txt"
        Start-Sleep -s 3
        $Result = Get-Content -path .\$list.txt
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more context. These are 3rdP tools and are not dependant on PowerShell. Sure, you can run this in a PowerShell session, but that, of course, is still not PowerShell. Yet, what you show is not a PowerShell specific issue. Are you saying you ran this and it is not working? Where / what are the errors. Loops are fully explained in the PowerShell docs. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4542.powershell-loops.aspx ---  Using the PowerShell_ISE, you start a new file, and Hit CRTL+J to show a list of snippets to use and loop samples are there as well.

Comment: Just create a variable or a file with your list (A00X-F1Z, A00X-F1Y, A00X-F1X, ... A00X-F1A) to check against, and loop with your needed logic.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow what you are asking as well. You have a list of Versions with A - Z at the end. What does result.txt have anything to do with these versions? Can you provide a sample of result.txt, that I assume already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I tested with what I gather you are looking for,

**Sample result.txt**

```
A00X-F1Z
A00X-F1Y
A00X-F1X
A00X-F1W
A00X-F1V
A00X-F1U
A00X-F1T
A00X-F1S
A00X-F1R
A00X-F1Q
```

**Code to work with**

```
$Version = "A00X-F1"
$List_Ver = 90..65 | ForEach-Object{"$Version" + [char]$_}
$result = Get-Content C:\temp\result.txt 
$string = "Folder Not Available"
foreach($list in $List_Ver) {
DownloadF.exe --net 10.0.0.1 --user XX --id 00 --ver $list >> result.txt
  if ($result -like $string ) {
    $n = 0
    while ($result -like $string)
    {
      $n++

     Write-Host "Not Found"
     Break
}
  }
  else {
     Write-Host "Found"
     Break
  }
}
```

Comment: HI @Jawad. THank you. The `result.txt` contain of string "Folder available" or "Folder not available" . `result.txt` will generate once this script executed `DownloadF.exe --net 10.0.0.1 --user XX --id 00 --ver $list >> result.txt`

Should we get this `$result = Get-Content C:\temp\result.txt ` before loop? because result.txt not exist yet.